# Dirichlet process in PyMC 3

Tags: pymc, theano, dirichlet, pymc3

I would like to implement to implement the Dirichlet process example referenced in
[Implementing Dirichlet processes for Bayesian semi-parametric models](http://stronginference.com/post/implementing-dirichlet-processes-for-bayesian-semi-parametric-models) (source: [here](https://github.com/fonnesbeck/pymc_radon/blob/master/radon_dp.py)) in PyMC 3.

In the example the stick-breaking probabilities are computed using the `pymc.deterministic`
decorator:

```
v = pymc.Beta('v', alpha=1, beta=alpha, size=N_dp)
@pymc.deterministic
def p(v=v):
    """ Calculate Dirichlet probabilities """

    # Probabilities from betas
    value = [u*np.prod(1-v[:i]) for i,u in enumerate(v)]
    # Enforce sum to unity constraint
    value[-1] = 1-sum(value[:-1])

    return value

 z = pymc.Categorical('z', p, size=len(set(counties)))
```

How would you implement this in PyMC 3 which is using Theano for the gradient computation?

edit:
I tried the following solution using the `theano.scan` method:

```
with pm.Model() as mod:
    conc = Uniform('concentration', lower=0.5, upper=10)
    v = Beta('v', alpha=1, beta=conc, shape=n_dp)
    p, updates = theano.scan(fn=lambda stick, idx: stick * t.prod(1 - v[:idx]),
                             outputs_info=None,
                             sequences=[v, t.arange(n_dp)])
    t.set_subtensor(p[-1], 1 - t.sum(p[:-1]))
    category = Categorical('category', p, shape=n_algs)
    sd = Uniform('precs', lower=0, upper=20, shape=n_dp)
    means = Normal('means', mu=0, sd=100, shape=n_dp)
    points = Normal('obs',
                    means[category],
                    sd=sd[category],
                    observed=data)

    step1 = pm.Slice([conc, v, sd, means])
    step3 = pm.ElemwiseCategoricalStep(var=category, values=range(n_dp))
    trace = pm.sample(2000, step=[step1, step3], progressbar=True)
```

Which sadly is really slow and does not obtain the original parameters of the synthetic data.

Is there a better solution and is this even correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I have a good answer but perhaps this could be sped up by instead using a theano blackbox op which allows you to write a distribution (or deterministic) in python code. E.g.: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/examples/disaster_model_arbitrary_deterministic.py

Comment: Here is a more direct example: https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/dp_mix.html